# Getting the value from the .txt file and displaying it in the current page using javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a HTML file which accepts input from textbox and Can you please help me with a simple programmatic steps ?When we enter the values in the textbox it gets stored in a .txt file and using AJAX opening the .txt file and printing the values in the textbox using jQuery or Javascript.

Comment: u said get value FROM .txt file.But you are taking values from textbox ,And storing it to server side. Can u please clarify wat u want to achieve?

Comment: In a HTML file there is a textbox,after getting the values from the text box I need to store it in the txt file and retrieve it to display it in an other HTML file

Comment: Then u need to use server side language like PHP  .which one u use?

Comment: I will have to do this by PHP then

Comment: May I have the syntax for this?

Comment: I provided readymade solution , care to comment?

Comment: Dude @Manikandan You have try first. Then we are happy to help you. Anyway! If you need my help. Please find me any of social network by searching `yeshansachithak`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following for Old age NON Ajax

```
<form action="saveFile.php" method="POST">
    <input name="saveText" type="text" id="saveText" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
```

//PHP

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
   $dataToSave=trim($_POST['saveText']);
   //Now do PHP file operations like open file , read , close file
   $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
   $txt = $dataToSave;
   fwrite($myfile, $txt);
   fclose($myfile);
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Or use following for Ajax(better solution,and better way to interact with server side)

```
<form action="saveFile.php" method="GET">
    <input name="saveText" type="text" id="saveText" />
    <input type="button" id="btn" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>


$("#btn").click(function(){
    var txtVal=$("#saveText").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "saveFile.php?txt="+txtVal
    });

});
```

//saveFile.php

```
if(isset($_GET['txt'])){
   $dataToSave=trim($_GET['txt']);
   //Now do PHP file operations like open file , read , close file
   $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
   $txt = $dataToSave;
   fwrite($myfile, $txt);
   fclose($myfile);
}
```

Comment: @Manikandan , you can Upvote (+1) if it satisfies your requirement.

Comment: Why downvoted ? Care to comment ? I tried on my Machine , and it works properly.Comment Downvoter

Comment: Ok, But someone downvoted.Downvoter should Comment !!